# Ir para o primeiro option depois de clicar no botão

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<select class="estados" name="estado">
    <option class="op1" value="">1</option>
    <option class="op2" value="">1</option>
    <option class="op3" value="">1</option>
</select>
<input type="reset" class="bt" value="refazer"/>
```

Digamos que eu selecionei o 3 `option op3`, quando eu clicar no `input class="bt"` quero que ele deixe marcado a 1ª opção `op1`.

Tenho que usar o [selected](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_input_selected.asp) do Jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você já souber o valor, dá para setá-lo diretamente pelo `val()`.

```
$("input.bt").on("click", function () {
    // no seu exemplo você não colocou nenhum value
    // nas options, mas aqui iria o value desejado
    $("select[name=estado]").val("valorNaOpcao1");
});
```

Se quiser selecionar sempre o primeiro, pode ser assim.

```
$("input.bt").on("click", function () {
    var $select = $("select[name=estado]");
    var $firstOption = $select.find("option:first-child");
    $select.val($firstOption.val());
});
```

ou

```
$("input.bt").on("click", function () {
    $("select[name=estado]").val($("select[name=estado] option:first-child").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os métodos `attr` e `removeAttr`.

Desse jeito:

```
$(".bt").click = function () {
  $(".op1").attr("selected", "selected");
  $(".op2").removeAttr("selected");
  $(".op3").removeAttr("selected");
};
```

E para ajudar a diferenciar a opção selecionada, faça assim:

```
<select class="estados" name="estado">
  <option class="op1" value="">1</option>
  <option class="op2" value="">2</option> <- Alteração do valor dentro da tag
  <option class="op3" value="">3</option> <- Alteração do valor dentro da tag
</select>
```

Comment: ah entendi, o que acontece é que os outros `options` serão gerenciáveis, esqueci de citar isso

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi...

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar a função [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) para setar a opção como marcada ao clicar no botão.

```js
$(".bt").click(function() {
  $(".op1").prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="estados" name="estado">
    <option class="op1" value="">1</option>
    <option class="op2" value="">2</option>
    <option class="op3" value="">3</option>
</select>
<input type="reset" class="bt" value="refazer"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se quiseres fazer um "reset", ou seja voltar ao valor inicial podes fazer assim:

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/suhjnxaj/**

```
$(".bt").on("click", function () {
    $("select.estados option").prop('selected', function() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });
});
```

Se quiseres forçar o primeiro somente podes fazer assim:

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/suhjnxaj/1/**

```
$(".bt").on("click", function () {
  $("select.estados option").each(function(i){
      $(this).removeAttr("selected");
      if (i == 0) this.selected = true; // onde o "i" é o index desse select, começando em zero
    });
});
```